# Must declare scalar variable @OrderHeaderId

Tags: c#, sql-server

Creating a shopping cart application and am getting an annoying error, I was able to figure out where the problem is (will point it out in the code).
Can anyone help me fix the actual error

```
public OrderItemList(int orderHeaderId)
    {
        SQLHelper db = new SQLHelper("OS");

        //get all the orders from the database

        string sql = "Select OrderHeaderId, StockItemId, Description, Orderitem.Price, Quantity from OrderItem inner join StockItem on OrderItem.StockItemId = StockItem.Id where OrderHeaderId = @OrderHeaderId"; (PROBLEM IS SOMEWHERE HERE) 
        //set up parameters
        SqlParameter[] objParams;
        objParams = new SqlParameter[1];
        objParams[0] = new SqlParameter("OrderHeaderId", DbType.Int32);
        objParams[0].Value = orderHeaderId;

        DataTable results = db.ExecuteSQL(sql, objParams);
        foreach (DataRow dr in results.Rows)
        {
            //Create data from DataRow
            Orderitem orderitem1 = new Orderitem(dr);
            //Add order collection's list
            this.Add(orderitem1);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @John that's worth a try, but my experience is that SqlClient (the provider here) doesn't care, and will work the same either way

Comment: @Abbass what is `SQLHelper` here? what does the `ExecuteSQL` API here take as parameters? do SQL parameters *normally* work like this? (I'm not familiar with that *particular* API, and want to rule out whether the problem is in the code we can't see; quietly mutters something about `connection.Query<OrderItem>("Select OrderHeaderId, StockItemId, Description, Orderitem.Price, Quantity from OrderItem inner join StockItem on OrderItem.StockItemId = StockItem.Id where OrderHeaderId = @orderHeaderId", new { orderHeaderId}).AsList();` from Dapper)

Comment: Hi, SQLHelper is basically a data access class, it has the try and catch method and all that stuff to test the code (including the ExecuteSQL method)

Comment: @Abbass Can you include the relevant section in your question?

Comment: we created it in my class (forgot to say im in college) for the assignment. Everything else works, but this error is the only problem

Comment: @AbbassAlasadi well it clearly *isn't* working, based on the fact that it isn't adding the parameter, so again: *can we see that*; we can't help you if the problem isn't in the code shown; so again, can we see the `ExecuteSQL` method

Comment: I just sent through the ExecuteSQL method through a picture @MarcGravell

Comment: @AbbassAlasadi it'll do, but in the future please note: *images* of code are the least useful way to share code - it is inaccessible for people using screen readers, and it doesn't allow people to look at the code in a code editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the parameters *after* you've executed the reader; you need to add them *before*. Move the `if parameters != null` check *much* earlier.

Additional:

- `dbConnection` is `IDisposable`, and thus should be declared with `using` - to ensure it is properly released
- ditto `dbCommand`
- ditto `dbDataReader`
- there's really no advantage to your `catch`/`throw` - just remove the `try`/`catch` here completely: it adds nothing, and loses a lot of context
- in reality, `DataTable` is *not* good practice; if this is college: fine, but please understand: this is not usually the preferred way to consume data